# Dreamweaver quit unexpectedly from Ajatix > Advanced CSS Drop Down Menu Light

Tags: c++, macos, entity-framework, flash, air

can you help me with this problem with Dreamweaver quit unexpectedly from Ajatix > Advanced CSS Drop Down Menu Light this is a add-on from creative cloud.
i do not know y this is happening to dreamweaver when i try to lode a program to add a menu bar

```
Process:         Dreamweaver [1111]
Path:            /Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/MacOS/Dreamweaver
Identifier:      com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0
Version:         12.0.0.5808 (12.0.0)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]
Responsible:     Dreamweaver [1111]`
User ID:         501


Date/Time:       2014-08-04 23:56:25.214 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  3339F2F3-5034-564D-287B-7F95E9E96A64

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ff28663e

VM Regions Near 0xff28663e:
    CG shared images       00000000c871f000-00000000c8727000 [   32K] r--/r-- SM=SHM  
--> 
    Submap                 00000000ffff0000-00000000ffff1000 [    4K] r--/r-- SM=PRV  process-only VM submap

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(dispatchMenuSelection:) from sender DVAMacMenuItem 0x15c91da0


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x004a8c44 MaybeSetupFrame + 272
1   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x004affce js_CompileTokenStream + 57
2   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x003e786a CompileTokenStream + 202
3   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x003e793f JS_CompileUCScriptForPrincipals + 85
4   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x003e79be JS_EvaluateUCScriptForPrincipals + 79
5   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x003e7a75 JS_EvaluateUCScript + 67
6   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x000f8802 JSInterp::ExecuteScript(Run*, TitanDoc*, unsigned short const*, unsigned short const*, unsigned short const*, long, unsigned short const*, CString*, JSInterp::ScriptMode, int, int, int, int, int, int) + 1670
7   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x009ee720 JSUICommand::CallExecuteOrKillFocusHandler(TitanDoc*, int, unsigned short const*, bool) + 1408
8   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x009ee993 JSUICommand::Execute(TitanDoc*, int, unsigned short const*) + 215
9   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x009c4710 JSMenusCommands::Execute(unsigned int) const + 312
10  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x009c0285 JSMenus::ExecuteCommand(unsigned int) const + 27
11  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0057a632 TitanMainFrame::OnExecuteJSMenuItem(unsigned int) + 34
12  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0112af71 CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int, int, void*, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO*) + 271
13  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0112b7d1 CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int, int, void*, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO*) + 121
14  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x01118881 CWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int, long) + 239
15  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0114c231 CMDIFrameWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int, long) + 85
16  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0121289f MMUI::COwlFrameWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int, long) + 85
17  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0057b46c TitanMainFrame::OnCommand(unsigned int, long) + 60
18  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x01116db0 CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int, unsigned int, long, long*) + 60
19  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x01116422 CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int, unsigned int, long) + 58
20  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x003a6fce CWnd::WinSendMessage(unsigned int, unsigned int, long) + 44
21  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x01138085 CRealApp::DoHandleCommand(int) + 369
22  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x01137f0b non-virtual thunk to CRealApp::DoHandleCommand(int) + 27
23  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x04111688 exo::uisupport::CommandHandler::HandleCommand(int) + 84
24  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x04110a83 exo::uisupport::CommandHandler::DoCallMyCommandChain(int) + 49
25  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x0410fd95 exo::uisupport::CommandHandlerBase::CallCommandChain(int) + 65
26  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x040ca364 exo::app::OS_AppBase::DispatchMenuCommand(int) + 146
27  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x040cacdf boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf1<void, exo::app::OS_AppBase, int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<exo::app::OS_AppBase*>, boost::_bi::value<int> > >, void>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) + 47
28  com.adobe.dvacore.framework   0x033e11fa int dvacore::config::ErrorManager::ExecuteFunction<void>(boost::function0<void>*, void*) + 36
29  com.adobe.dvacore.framework   0x033e20f8 boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker0<boost::_bi::bind_t<int, int (*)(boost::function0<void>*, void*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::function0<void>*>, boost::_bi::value<void*> > >, int>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) + 24
30  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x01139fa8 TestErrorManager::ExecuteFunctionWithTopLevelExceptionHandler(boost::function0<int>) + 50
31  com.adobe.dvacore.framework   0x033e10ef void dvacore::config::ErrorManager::ExecuteFunctionWithTopLevelExceptionHandler<void>(boost::function0<void>, bool*) + 135
32  com.adobe.dvacore.framework   0x033e3bb1 void dvacore::config::ExecuteTopLevelFunction<void>(boost::function0<void>, bool*) + 129
33  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x040c8e6e -[ExoMacApplication handleMenuCommand:] + 174
34  com.adobe.dvaui.framework     0x03997192 -[DVAMacMenuItem dispatchMenuSelection:] + 66
35  libobjc.A.dylib               0x9a7352af -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
36  com.apple.AppKit               0x929878a5 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 438
37  com.apple.AppKit               0x929a3c65 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 486
38  com.apple.AppKit               0x929a396a -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 163
39  com.apple.AppKit               0x929a3021 -[NSMenu _performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:sendAccessibilityNotification:] + 79
40  com.apple.AppKit               0x929f6664 -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 65
41  com.adobe.dvaui.framework     0x03996c1a -[DVAMacMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] + 58
42  com.apple.AppKit               0x929f6619 -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 45
43  com.apple.AppKit               0x929f65e4 -[NSMenuItem _internalPerformActionThroughMenuIfPossible] + 106
44  com.apple.AppKit               0x929f6434 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 120
45  com.apple.AppKit               0x92998da6 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 816
46  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x98148d89 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
47  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x97f9c34f DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1452
48  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x97f9b668 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 386
49  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x97fae811 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
50  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x98148c2e SendHICommandEvent(unsigned long, HICommand const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) + 478
51  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x98011ef7 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 70
52  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x98011ea4 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 199
53  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x98011d72 FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) + 134
54  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x9819d59d MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned long, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 722
55  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x9801970e _HandleMenuSelection2 + 488
56  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x98019517 _HandleMenuSelection + 53
57  com.apple.AppKit               0x92906298 _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 358
58  com.apple.AppKit               0x9275b6a2 _DPSNextEvent + 2459
59  com.apple.AppKit               0x9275a870 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
60  com.apple.AppKit               0x9274d15c -[NSApplication run] + 727
61  com.adobe.exo.framework       0x040c8bd3 exo::app::OS_AppBase::RunEventLoop() + 67
62  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0113840f CRealApp::Run() + 395
63  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0111bc80 CWinAppImpl::Run() + 36
64  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x0111bf6f main + 95
65  com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x004dcdf5 start + 53


Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586c992 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x96e78899 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x96e78532 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64c25 pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   com.adobe.boost_threads.framework 0x0282526e boost::condition_variable::timed_wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, boost::posix_time::ptime const&) + 812
4   com.adobe.boost_threads.framework 0x0281e680 boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::ptime const&) + 128
5   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x008fc336 JSInterp::testForINET() + 110
6   com.adobe.dreamweaver-12.0     0x008fd095 boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker0<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, JSInterp>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<JSInterp*> > >, void>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&) + 37
7   com.adobe.dvacore.framework   0x0342db37 dvacore::threads::(anonymous namespace)::LaunchThread(std::string const&, boost::function0<void> const&, dvacore::threads::ThreadPriority, boost::function<void ()> const&, boost::function<void ()> const&) + 151
8   com.adobe.dvacore.framework   0x0342dc48 boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(std::string const&, boost::function0<void> const&, dvacore::threads::ThreadPriority, boost::function<void ()> const&, boost::function<void ()> const&), boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<std::string>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()> >, boost::_bi::value<dvacore::threads::ThreadPriority>, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()> >, boost::_bi::value<boost::function<void ()> > > > >::run() + 64
9   com.adobe.boost_threads.framework 0x0281d737 thread_proxy + 167
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586bb76 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x9015dfb7 nanosleep$UNIX2003 + 219
2   com.apple.carbonbundletemplate 0x11c8d4db ScObjects::Thread::sleep(unsigned int) + 59
3   com.apple.carbonbundletemplate 0x11c89339 ScObjects::BridgeTalkThread::run() + 185
4   com.apple.carbonbundletemplate 0x11c8d848 ScObjects::Thread::go(void*) + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586ba26 __recvfrom + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x9015e0c9 recv$UNIX2003 + 54
2   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12415733 Invoke + 47867
3   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12414846 Invoke + 44046
4   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12413988 Invoke + 40272
5   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12413a0f Invoke + 40407
6   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x1240ebaf Invoke + 20343
7   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x1240eea7 Invoke + 21103
8   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x1240f685 Invoke + 23117
9   ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x1240f8f9 Invoke + 23745
10  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x124122a0 Invoke + 34408
11  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x124123fd Invoke + 34757
12  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12412c91 Invoke + 36953
13  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12412db2 Invoke + 37242
14  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12405656 Login + 461
15  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x1240909a Login + 15377
16  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x12413165 Invoke + 38189
17  ServiceManager-Launcher.dylib 0x124152eb Invoke + 46771
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e904f APXGetHostAPI + 2633743
4   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x1247a62f APXGetHostAPI + 83439
5   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e913e APXGetHostAPI + 2633982
6   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e91a7 APXGetHostAPI + 2634087
7   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e92c6 APXGetHostAPI + 2634374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e904f APXGetHostAPI + 2633743
4   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x1247a62f APXGetHostAPI + 83439
5   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e913e APXGetHostAPI + 2633982
6   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e91a7 APXGetHostAPI + 2634087
7   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e92c6 APXGetHostAPI + 2634374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e904f APXGetHostAPI + 2633743
4   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x1247a62f APXGetHostAPI + 83439
5   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e913e APXGetHostAPI + 2633982
6   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e91a7 APXGetHostAPI + 2634087
7   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e92c6 APXGetHostAPI + 2634374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e904f APXGetHostAPI + 2633743
4   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x1247a62f APXGetHostAPI + 83439
5   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e913e APXGetHostAPI + 2633982
6   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e91a7 APXGetHostAPI + 2634087
7   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e92c6 APXGetHostAPI + 2634374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d8a _pthread_cond_wait + 837
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d63042 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e9017 APXGetHostAPI + 2633687
4   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x1270220e APXGetHostAPI + 2736590
5   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e913e APXGetHostAPI + 2633982
6   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e91a7 APXGetHostAPI + 2634087
7   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e92c6 APXGetHostAPI + 2634374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d8a _pthread_cond_wait + 837
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d63042 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e9017 APXGetHostAPI + 2633687
4   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x12877168 APXGetHostAPI + 4264232
5   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e913e APXGetHostAPI + 2633982
6   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e91a7 APXGetHostAPI + 2634087
7   com.adobe.ape.engine           0x126e92c6 APXGetHostAPI + 2634374
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d8a _pthread_cond_wait + 837
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64fa3 pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5025f 0x16800000 + 4522591
4   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x1681a39f 0x16800000 + 107423
5   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5034c 0x16800000 + 4522828
6   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c50390 0x16800000 + 4522896
7   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c504b6 0x16800000 + 4523190
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d8a _pthread_cond_wait + 837
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64fa3 pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5025f 0x16800000 + 4522591
4   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x1681a39f 0x16800000 + 107423
5   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5034c 0x16800000 + 4522828
6   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c50390 0x16800000 + 4522896
7   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c504b6 0x16800000 + 4523190
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d8a _pthread_cond_wait + 837
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64fa3 pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5025f 0x16800000 + 4522591
4   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x1681a39f 0x16800000 + 107423
5   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5034c 0x16800000 + 4522828
6   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c50390 0x16800000 + 4522896
7   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c504b6 0x16800000 + 4523190
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d8a _pthread_cond_wait + 837
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64fa3 pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5025f 0x16800000 + 4522591
4   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x1681a39f 0x16800000 + 107423
5   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c5034c 0x16800000 + 4522828
6   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c50390 0x16800000 + 4522896
7   com.macromedia.Flash Player.authplaylib 0x16c504b6 0x16800000 + 4523190
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x95866f7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586616c mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f57bf9 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f571d1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1393
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f569ea CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f5684b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.AppKit               0x92904b88 _NSEventThread + 283
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 16:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x95866f7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586616c mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f57bf9 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f571d1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1393
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f569ea CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94f5684b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Foundation           0x936b9095 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 381
7   com.apple.Foundation           0x936b8f0e -[NSThread main] + 45
8   com.apple.Foundation           0x936b8e66 __NSThread__main__ + 1426
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 17:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586bace __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x94fa7ae6 __CFSocketManager + 1158
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586b7ca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d62d1d _pthread_cond_wait + 728
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d64bd9 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   WebKitDw.dylib                 0x1e91a273 WTF::TCMalloc_PageHeap::scavengerThread() + 179
4   WebKitDw.dylib                 0x1e91a2e1 WTF::TCMalloc_PageHeap::runScavengerThread(void*) + 17
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d605fb _pthread_body + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d60485 _pthread_start + 130
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cf2 thread_start + 34


Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586c046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d61dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cce start_wqthread + 30


Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586c046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d61dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cce start_wqthread + 30


Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x9586c046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d61dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x96d65cce start_wqthread + 30


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0xff2866f2  ebx: 0xbfffd500  ecx: 0x000000b0  edx: 0x09d4cdf0
  edi: 0xff2865f2  esi: 0x09647350  ebp: 0xbfffd4d8  esp: 0xbfffd4c0
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010282  eip: 0x004a8c44   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xff28663e

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: This looks pretty much like a question that should be addressed to the [Dreamweaver Support Center](https://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/downloads_updaters.html), rather than to Stack Exchange.

Comment: ok just seeing if anyone could help on this problem

Comment: _'ok just seeing if anyone could help on this problem'_ I seriously doubt it, but good luck!